# Interpretation of plot in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

i have recently started working with R and i am trying to see relationship between two quantitative variable F and test
my script is

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x = read.table("Input.txt", header = T)
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = F, y = Test)) +
  geom_point(colour = "red")
cor(x$F, x$Test)

ggplot(data = x, aes(x = sqrt(F), y = sqrt(Test))) +
  geom_point(colour = "red")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

lmodel = lm(sqrt(Test) ~ sqrt(F), data = x)
```

the results are attached

```
summary(lmodel)

Call:
lm(formula = sqrt(Test) ~ sqrt(F), data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3140.9 -2575.8 -1779.5  -146.2 18137.6 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     2818       3910   0.721    0.479
sqrt(F)         2169       7668   0.283    0.780

Residual standard error: 5233 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003796,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.04364 
F-statistic: 0.08001 on 1 and 21 DF,  p-value: 0.78
```

i just dont understand R manual about summary output.

if i just look at p value of linear model its bad and correlation tells there is no linear relationship

can anyone help me in understanding this.

can anybody tell my script is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find some more information on the interpretation of `summary` in the following link.

https://feliperego.github.io/blog/2015/10/23/Interpreting-Model-Output-In-R

Your p-value, which is always between 0 and 1, is interpreted the following way.

1. A small `p-value` says there is a strong evidence against your null hypothesis.
2. A large `p-value` says the evidence against the null hypothesis is weak.

Your `p-value` here is significantly close to 1. But no, it doesn´t mean your model is bad.

College stats professor Stephen Tigler said that *unusually* high p values indicated the data matched the model suspiciously well... This is, a high `p-value` suggests that there is practically no correlation or association between your data. It´s kind of like an indicator of *randomness*. An indication of how much chance you have of observing a correlation like the one you already have.

Also, as you are guessing, there seems to be no relationship between both of your variables. Your R-squared statistic provides a measure of how well fitted your model is. The closer to 1, the better...

Comment: thank you so much . but r2 here is close to 0. does it mean that model is not fitted well